# Redirect rules in windows host

Tags: .htaccess, iis

I have a widows machine hosted by goddady and I need to create a rule to forward any request with a URL pointing to a non-existing file to be sent to the index.php.
Usually I would do that with the .htaccess but its different in windows hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I had to put a xml file named 'web.conf' in the root directory, it works in the same way .htaccess does.
I took the rules from [ZendFramework Site](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.rewrite.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsFile" pattern=""
                             ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsDirectory"
                             pattern=""
                             ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This rules will make the server check if the file exsists and if it doesn't then the request is forwarded to index.php